# Convert UL to SELECT for mobile, then back again on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a bit of code that I run when the window width is less than 400px. It converts the UL to a `select` dropdown to save space and give mobile users the native interface for select groups.

I'm concerned that this will break when people are resizing the window from small to big and back again. How do I reset my code on resize if the window width is bigger than 400px?

Here is the code that converts my html to the select:

http://jsfiddle.net/2GM8v/1/

```
    if($(window).width() < 400){ //if we're on a narrow screen

      $('section ul',this.$element).hide();

      // Create the dropdown base
      $("<select />").appendTo(".continents",this.$element);

      // Create default option "Go to..."
      $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value"   : "",
        "text"    : $('.continents span.selected',this.$element).text()
      }).appendTo(".continents select",this.$element);

      // Populate dropdown with menu items
      $(".continents li a",this.$element).each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<option />", {
          "value"   : el.attr("href"),
          "text"    : el.text()
        }).appendTo(".continents select",this.$element);
      });

      $(".continents select",this.$element).change(function() {

      //get the value of the selected item
      var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

      //when the select changes, do this

      $("<select />").appendTo('.countries',this.$element);

      // Create default option "Go to..."
      $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value"   : "",
        "text"    : $('.countries span.selected',this.$element).text()
      }).appendTo(".countries select",this.$element);

      // Populate dropdown with menu items
      $(selectVal+" li a",this.$element).each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<option />", {
          "value"   : el.attr("href"),
          "text"    : el.text()
        }).appendTo(".countries select",this.$element);
      });

      $(".countries select",this.$element).change(function() {

        //get the value of the selected item
        var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

        //when the select changes, do this

        $("<select />").appendTo('.languages',this.$element);

        // Create default option "Go to..."
        $("<option />", {
          "selected": "selected",
          "value"   : "",
          "text"    : $('.languages span.selected',this.$element).text()
        }).appendTo(".languages select",this.$element);

        // Populate dropdown with menu items
        $(selectVal+" li a").each(function() {
          var el = $(this);
          $("<option />", {
            "value"   : el.closest('li').data('val'),
            "text"    : el.text()
          }).appendTo(".languages select",this.$element);
        });

        $(".languages select",this.$element).change(function() {
            var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $('#continue',this.$element).removeClass('disabled');
            $('#continue',this.$element).attr('href', selectVal);
        });

      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a `select` on all devices in the first place?

Comment: Because I'm doing something completely different, functionality wise and design wise on desktop.

Comment: The code in its original state is also functioning as a non-js page (loads of ul's), styled for desktop with JS in one way and the requirement is to have select boxes for mobile.

Comment: In that case it sounds like this would be better suited to server-side code. Detect user agent on the server side and display a `select` instead of a `ul` where necessary. Otherwise you're just increasing the load time on mobile browsers.

Comment: You don't need JS. On your markup create both the `ul` and `select`. Then use CSS media queries to show only one of them.

Comment: I don't want to maintain two sections of HTML in my CMS.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the `<ul>` to a variable and replace the `<select>` with it when the window is above 400px.

```
  $ul = $('.continents ul');

  // on.('resize... 
  if($(window).width() < 400) {
     // Your function
  } else if (!$('.continents ul').length) {
     $('.continents select').replaceWith($ul);
  }
```

Comment: This looks promising, will give it a go. Thanks!